# How to override pub/error folder in my module for magento 2 cloud?

Tags: magento2, error, magento2-cloud

How to override pub/error folder in my module for magento 2 cloud ?

I want override **pub/errors folders** in my module for magento 2 cloud enterprise edition.

**I tried following method**

> 1. Copy `pub/errors/local.xml.sample` to `pub/errors/local.xml`
> 2. Then made a copy of `pub/errors/default` (let's say
>    `pub/errors/custom`).

Changed the `skin` value of the `pub/errors/local.xml` to the newly created errors skin:

```
<config>
    <skin>custom</skin>
    ....
```

**But cloud is not allowing me to `mkdir` create directory over there.**

Any solution for cloud enterprise edition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy your files on build phase during composer install from your module to some destination.

Just create a mapping in composer.json of your module.

More information https://github.com/magento/magento-composer-installer

Comment: Thanks for the answer +1 for that, but this issue is regarding Magento cloud enterprise edition.

Comment: @AdityaShah on the build phase FS is writable and this approach helps you.
on the deploy phase FS is read-only, and you can write only into `app/etc`, `pub/static`, `pub/media`, `var`

As an option, you can add the directory `pub/errors` to git