# Override /pub/media/... css file?

Tags: magento2, css, frontend

I would like to override a CSS file who is here :

```
/pub/media/porto/web/css/header/type6.css
```

But when I try to put it in my child theme nothing happen :

```
/app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/...
```

So, my question is : Is it possible to override css files located in pub/media ? And if yes, how can I do it ?

Thank you all for your attention.

Comment: I assume you are using Porto theme. Doesnt the Porto theme have a panel for css overrides. Stores > Configuration > Porto > Porto - Settings Panel > Customization?

Comment: This is helpful to you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/243185/how-to-override-pub-error-folder-in-my-module-for-magento-2-cloud